# yammer get user token yammer REST API

Tags: c#, rest, yammer

I'm trying to add user to Yammer group, For this I need to have the token of the user whom I want to add to the group. I've used the following endpoint to access the user token

```
https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/oauth/tokens.json?user_id={0}&consumer_key={1}
```

For consumer_key I'm passing the ClientID of the yammer application that I've created (using Verified admin account).

The problem is that for some user the endpoint is working fine and returning me the JSON response. But for some user the endpoint is returning "**The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**"

Please, find my code below

```
private YammerJSONUserContract GetUserDetailsFromYammer(string userID, string clientID)
    {
        YammerJSONUserContract objUser = null;
        try
        {
            string URL = string.Format(this.userImpersonationURL, userID, clientID);
            string jsonString = PostYammerJson(URL, this._adminAccessToken, "GET");
            YammerJSONUserContract [] objUserCollection = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YammerJSONUserContract[]>(jsonString);
            objUser = objUserCollection[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return objUser;
    }
private string PostYammerJson(string url, string accessToken, string httpMethod)
    {
        string json = string.Empty;
        try
        {

            HttpWebRequest YammerRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            YammerRequest.Method = httpMethod;
            YammerRequest.ContentType = "application/json; odata=verbose";
            YammerRequest.Accept = "application/json; odata=verbose";
            YammerRequest.ContentLength = 0;
            YammerRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Concat("Bearer ", accessToken));
            using (HttpWebResponse response = YammerRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                Encoding encode = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encode);
                json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return json;
    }
```

Can someone please let me know what I'm missing and why the API returning the user details for some users but not all.

Waiting for your response.

Cheers 
Amlan

Comment: What is PostYammerJson? Please post the code of that as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot but maybe you need to add Authorization header to your request with value "oauth".

Something like:

```
request.Headers.Authorization = oauth;
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you get a successful token for some users but a 400 error for others so I'm assuming you're formatting the call correctly.  The only other variable is the user.  Have you verified the users for which it's giving you a 400 error are active and not in a pending, suspended, or deleted state?